# Why does my click event require two clicks (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen some solutions for other frameworks but none apply to me. I have two main issues here.

1- I have to click the button twice to get it to fire. Granted I am using the click even't to mutate the state, change the row color, AND also update a list on the bottom of the table. I don't think none of these are running asynchronously. So maybe that's the problem and I would like to know how to go around that.

2- Second problem is related to the first. I passed the dependency in the useEffect function so that the list on the bottom is updated as soon as the click event changes the state. But it's throwing an infinite loop, as if the state was constantly changing. A console log doesn't reflect the state forever changing. So, I'm stooped.

Some basically I have an array (API in real world), and I'm filtering out the learned and unlearned questions

```
const questions = [
  { 
    question: "Question 1",
    answer: "My answer 1",
    learned: true
  },
  {
    question: "Question 2",
    answer: "My answer 2",
    learned: false
  },
  {
    question: "Question 3",
    answer: "My answer 3",
    learned: true
  },
  {
    question: "Question 4",
    answer: "My answer 4",
    learned: true
  },
  {
    question: "Question 5",
    answer: "My answer 5",
    learned: false
  },
  {
    question: "Question 6",
    answer: "My answer 6",
    learned: true
  }
]

const learned = questions.filter(question => question.learned === true)
const unlearned = questions.filter(question => question.learned === false)
```

Inside my component I have the state, the function to populate a list, useEffect, and a click event function that contains the callback to populate the list, as well as toggling the UI from learned to unlearned, which of course, it updates the list accordingly

```
const [unlearned, setUnlearned] = useState([]);

const populateUnlearned = () => {
  setUnlearned(questions.filter(question => question.learned === false))
}

useEffect(() => {
  populateUnlearned()
},[]) //unlearned here causes the list to populate fine but an infinite loop

const handleLearned = (index) => {  
  populateUnlearned()
  setIsLearned(
    !isLearned, 
    questions.filter(question => question.learned === false), 
    questions[index].learned = !isLearned
  )
}
```

And the rest is just html stuff. I have a [**sandbox here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-antonelli-6jpxpr) for you to mess with showing the problem.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does the `isLearned` variable come from? I recommend removing the `useState` and `useEffect`; they are not needed. Use `const unlearned = questions.filter` on every render, 99% chance it has no noticeable effect on rendering,

Comment: isLearned is used for toggling the learned prop from true to false and viseversa. Which will be sent in the header later in a POST request to submit the quiz answers

Comment: The `questions` array is declared outside the component. When the code does `questions[x].learned = true;`, React is unaware there was an update and therefore cannot know it should re-render. There must be something in React's state that updates so it knows to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are a few updates I would recommend,

1. State variables

In Vocabulary.js, you attempt to modify the entries in `questions`. However, this variable is not a piece of state. Keep in mind that only variables created based on `useState` (and `useReducer`) can be updated within your component

2. Avoid performing updates based on index

[here](https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/) you can find information that explains in detail why you should not be using the index

```js
// rename questions to original_questions
const original_questions = [
 {
  ...

// compute them within the component
//const learned = questions.filter((question) => question.learned === true);
//const unlearned = questions.filter((question) => question.learned === false);
```

```js
const Vocabulary = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);

  // unneeded since each entry in "questions" keeps track that flag
  // const [isLearned, setIsLearned] = useState(false);

  // questions get initiated as a piece of state
  // based on the original_questions (this can be a prop)
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState(original_questions);
  const [unlearned, setUnlearned] = useState([]);

  // effects computes unlearned
  // whenever questions state changes
  useEffect(() => {
    populateUnlearned();
  }, [questions]);

  // other functions...
  

  // instead of index,
  // handleLearned expects the row data 
  // (ideally row should have a unique id e.g row.id)
  // the update uses the `question` property to uniquely identify
  // the question to update 
  const handleLearned = (row) => {
    setQuestions((currentQuestions) =>
      currentQuestions.map((entry) => {
        if (row.question === entry.question) { 
          entry.learned = !entry.learned;
        }
        return entry;
      })
    );
    //populateUnlearned();
    //setIsLearned(
    //  !isLearned,
    //  questions.filter((question) => question.learned === false),
    //  (questions[index].learned = !isLearned)
    //);
    // setUnlearned(questions.filter(question => question.learned === false))
    // questions[index].learned = !isLearned
  };


  // more code ...
  // button onClick callback now gets the row instead of index
  <StyledTableCell align="center">
                  <Button
                    onClick={() => handleLearned(row)} 
                    variant="contained"
                    color={row.learned ? "error" : "success"}
                    size="small"
                    sx={{ mr: 2 }}
                  >
                    {row.learned ? "No" : "Yes"}
                  </Button>
                </StyledTableCell>
```

Comment: Outstanding!!!!! Wow, I had no idea I had so much going on in there. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
questions[index].learned = !questions[index].learned
```

instead of

```
questions[index].learned = !isLearned
```

You can't use single boolean to hold the current state of `learned` on each row. You don't even need a separate state for that, you are already holding it in `questions[index].learned`, you just have to invert it

It is not the `React` way of doing so, but it will work, you just have to be sure that there is a rerender after setting the new value to `questions[index].learned`

And setIsLearned does not accept that many parameters, it accepts only 1 to change its value

And not everything have to be state. You don't need `unlearned` state as well. You already have the array `questions`, you can filter it while rendering. If it is an expensive operation, instead of moving it to a separate state, you can use `useMemo`

You can remove `isLearned` and `unlearned` states and move `questions` to its own state

```
const unlearned = questions.filter(question => question.learned === false)
```

This is just enough, no need of state

Comment: That fixed the double click. Thank you for that. I can't remove the isLearned however because it is controlling the learned boolean value so I can make a ternary condition for the row color and button value. And depending on whether it is true or false it updates the filter in the unlearned variable